# finding all non-unique lines in a file

Tags: uniq

I'm trying to use uniq to find all non-unique lines in a file.  By non-unique, I mean any line that I have already seen on the previous line. I thought that the "-D" option would do this:

```
-D     print all duplicate lines
```

But instead of just printing the duplicate lines, it prints *all* the lines when there is more than one.  I want to only print the second and subsequent copies of a line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU or ast-open implementation of `uniq`:

```
uniq -D -u < input
```

(`-D` itself is non-standard), though note that it's the last duplicate that it removes, not the first (which makes a difference if you also use `-i`, `-w` or `-f`)

Portably, you could always use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $0 "" == previous ""; {previous = $0}' < input
```

(the concatenation with `""` being to force a string comparison even if operands look like numbers)

To only compare the first 9 characters (note that `-w` is also a GNU extension and (currently) works with bytes, not characters (despite what its document says)):

```
awk '{current = substr($0, 1, 9)}
     NR > 1 && current == previous
     {previous = current}' < input
```

(no need for `""` concatenation in that case as `substr()` returns a string).

In a UTF-8 locale, on the output of

```
printf '%s\n' StéphaneChazelas StéphaneUNIX StéphaneUnix
```

It gives `StéphaneUnix` as expected while `uniq -w9 -D -u` (with GNU `uniq`) gives `StéphaneChazelas` and `StéphaneUNIX` as `Stéphane` is 8 characters but 9 bytes in UTF-8 whilst ast-open `uniq` gives StéphaneUNIX only (`awk` skips the first occurrence, `uniq` removes the last occurrence).

With `awk`, you can also report all duplicate lines even when they're not adjacent with:

```
 awk 'seen[$0]++' < input
```

(note that it stores all the unique lines in memory in a hash table though).

Or to consider only the first 9 characters:

```
 awk 'seen[substr($0, 1, 9)]++' < input
```

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!  in my case i'm actually using the `--check-chars` option as well, so something like `substr($0,9) == substr(previous,9)` I guess (although that doesn't match anything for some reason)

Comment: ah, `substr($0,1,9) == substr(previous,1,9)` works.

Comment: @Michael, see edit for more options

Answer (score 2):

You want the lowercase -d option of the GNU version.

```
# printf "a\na\na\nb\nb\nc\n" | uniq -d
a
b
```

Comment: that's only printing one copy when there are duplicates.  if there are 9 instances of a line, i want it to print the last 8.

Comment: Note that `-d` is [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/uniq.html). It's `-D` that's not.

Comment: I misunderstood.  At this point you might need to use somthing a bit more Turing complete to solve the problem (like awk above, or shell scripting)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `-c`  of uniq , and after remove what you want

```
e444$ (   echo a ; echo a ; echo b ; echo d ; echo d ; echo e )  | uniq -c
  2 a
  1 b
  2 d
  1 e
```

`a`  and `d`  are in  duplicate and `b`and `e`  are in double

```
e444$ (   echo a ; echo a ; echo b ; echo d ; echo d ; echo e )  | uniq -c  \             
              | sed -E '/^ *1 .$/d;s/^ *[0-9]+ //'
```

explanation of the `sed`  expression :

`/^ *1 .$/d` will delete all uniques lines

`s/^ *[0-9]+ //`  will remove the counter